# c++ интерполяция как в ES6

Tags: c++, g++

Добрый день, есть ли интерполяция как в ES6 в C++?

```js
var desc = "smartest";
console.log(`The ${desc} IDE`)
```

Может быть библиотека или встроенная функция,

P.S printf это не совсем то что нужно.

Comment: Встроенной нету, возможно подойдёт [fmtlib](https://github.com/fmtlib/fmt)

Comment: https://studiofreya.com/cpp/boost/a-few-boostformat-examples/